# Why is rp424 always capitalized in Excel?

Tags: excel

I am creating a spreadsheet where the first column is an alphanumeric ID, starting with letters and ending with digits.

I have a user ID, rp424, which for some reason is always automatically capitalized to Rp424 and right-justified when I enter it, along with other IDs, into an Excel spreadsheet. Does this correspond to some pattern specific to Excel for formatting?

Comment: Do you have any Macros installed?  I just auto-filled rpt1 through rpt500 in a spreadsheet and all were lower-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spreadsheet thinks `Rp` stands for [rupiah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indonesian_rupiah), the official currency of Indonesia. Turn off the currency formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Check your [automatic correction](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/turn-automatic-corrections-on-or-off-HP005201718.aspx) options.

Office applications feature automatic correction to make life easier. Lowercase/uppercase conversion is one of them.